# Checkstyle suppress all checks on files that have a particular package in their path

Tags: java, checkstyle

I would like to exclude java files that have the package `example` in their path, such that:

```java
com.mystuff.myapp.example.res.Account.java
```

and

```java
com.mystuff.myapp.example.Account.java
```

are excluded, but

```java
com.mystuff.myapp.some.other.package.Account.java
```

is not.

I have tried heaps of variations

For example, I have found that

```xml
<suppress files="[\\/]example[\\/].*\.java$" checks=".*" />
```

doesn't work because it'll only exclude **direct** descendents of `example` not **all** descendents.

So how do you exclude all descendents.

Comment: Well, your regex isn't perfect (wouldn't be limited to java files), but it achieves the goal of excluding everything below `example`, including subpackages. I tried it [here](https://regex101.com/r/oc0Wt8/1). Can you verify?

Comment: yes, you're correct. The regex is good enough. I think I confused myself whilst looking at the roughly 4000 checkstyle errors my code was kicking out.

Answer (score 0):

For the case that you are using maven - you could also exclude files with the  configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>**/.java</excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

But for the case that (as you mentioned in your comment) regexp works and only the massive number of checkstyle errors is your problem, then please note that you should first create your own checkstyle config!

This will take time to read and understand every option and to configure it on your own requirements!

For example my(!) personal checkstyle-config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
  <property name="severity" value="warning"/>

  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="AnnotationLocation"/>
    <!-- <module name="AnnotationOnSameLine"/> -->
    <module name="AnnotationUseStyle"/>
    <module name="MissingDeprecated"/>
    <module name="MissingOverride"/>
    <module name="PackageAnnotation"/>
    <module name="SuppressWarnings"/>
    <module name="SuppressWarningsHolder"/>

    <!-- Block Checks -->
    <module name="AvoidNestedBlocks">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyBlock">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="option" value="text"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyCatchBlock"/>
    <module name="LeftCurly">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="option" value="nl"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, CTOR_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED, LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_WHILE, METHOD_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NeedBraces">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RightCurly">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="option" value="alone"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, CLASS_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_WHILE, LITERAL_DO"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Class Design -->
    <module name="DesignForExtension"/>
    <module name="FinalClass">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="HideUtilityClassConstructor">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="InnerTypeLast"/>
    <module name="InterfaceIsType">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MutableException"/>
    <module name="OneTopLevelClass"/>
    <module name="ThrowsCount"/>
    <module name="VisibilityModifier">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Coding -->
    <!-- <module name="ArrayTrailingComma"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="AvoidInlineConditionals"/> -->
    <module name="CovariantEquals"/>
    <module name="DeclarationOrder"/>
    <module name="DefaultComesLast"/>
    <module name="EmptyStatement">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EqualsAvoidNull"/>
    <module name="EqualsHashCode">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ExplicitInitialization"/>
    <module name="FallThrough"/>
    <module name="FinalLocalVariable"/>
    <module name="HiddenField">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="ignoreConstructorParameter" value="true"/>
      <property name="ignoreSetter" value="true"/>
      <property name="setterCanReturnItsClass" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <!-- TODO Enable later
    <module name="IllegalCatch"/>
    -->
    <module name="IllegalInstantiation">
      <property name="classes" value="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    </module>
    <module name="IllegalThrows"/>
    <module name="IllegalToken"/>
    <module name="IllegalTokenText"/>
    <module name="IllegalType"/>
    <module name="InnerAssignment">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <!-- TODO Enable later
    <module name="MagicNumber">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    -->
    <!-- <module name="MissingCtor"/> -->
    <module name="MissingSwitchDefault">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ModifiedControlVariable"/>
    <!-- TODO Enable later
    <module name="MultipleStringLiterals"/>
    -->
    <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations"/>
    <module name="NestedForDepth">
      <property name="max" value="3"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NestedIfDepth">
      <property name="max" value="4"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NestedTryDepth">
      <property name="max" value="2"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NoClone"/>
    <module name="NoFinalizer"/>
    <module name="OneStatementPerLine"/>
    <module name="OverloadMethodsDeclarationOrder"/>
    <module name="PackageDeclaration"/>
    <module name="ParameterAssignment"/>
    <!-- <module name="RequireThis"/> -->
    <module name="ReturnCount">
      <property name="max" value="7"/>
      <!-- <property name="maxForVoid" value="2"/> -->
    </module>
    <module name="SimplifyBooleanExpression">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SimplifyBooleanReturn">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="StringLiteralEquality"/>
    <module name="SuperClone"/>
    <module name="SuperFinalize"/>
    <!-- <module name="UnnecessaryParentheses"/> -->
    <module name="VariableDeclarationUsageDistance"/>

    <!-- Imports -->
    <module name="AvoidStarImport">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <!-- <module name="AvoidStaticImport"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="CustomImportOrder"/> -->
    <module name="IllegalImport">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <!-- <module name="ImportControl"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="ImportOrder"/> -->
    <module name="RedundantImport">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="UnusedImports">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Javadoc Comments -->
    <module name="AtclauseOrder"/>
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <!-- <module name="JavadocParagraph"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="JavadocStyle"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="JavadocTagContinuationIndentation"/> -->
    <module name="JavadocType">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocVariable">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NonEmptyAtclauseDescription"/>
    <module name="SingleLineJavadoc"/>
    <module name="SummaryJavadocCheck"/>
    <!-- <module name="WriteTag"/> -->

    <!-- Metrics -->
    <!-- <module name="BooleanExpressionComplexity"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="ClassDataAbstractionCoupling"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="ClassFanOutComplexity"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="CyclomaticComplexity"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="JavaNCSS"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="NPathComplexity"/> -->

    <!-- Miscellaneous -->
    <module name="ArrayTypeStyle">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidEscapedUnicodeCharacters"/>
    <module name="CommentsIndentation"/>
    <!-- <module name="DescendantToken"/> -->
    <module name="FinalParameters">
      <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF,CTOR_DEF,LITERAL_CATCH"/>
    </module>
    <!-- TODO
    <module name="Indentation">
      <property name="basicOffset" value="2"/>
      <property name="braceAdjustment" value="1"/>
      <property name="caseIndent" value="2"/>
      <property name="throwsIndent" value="2"/>
      <property name="arrayInitIndent" value="2"/>
      <property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="2"/>
    </module>
    -->
    <module name="OuterTypeFilename"/>
    <!--
    <module name="TodoComment">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    -->
    <!--
    <module name="TrailingComment"/>
    -->
    <module name="UncommentedMain"/>
    <module name="UpperEll">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Modifiers -->
    <module name="ModifierOrder">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RedundantModifier">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Naming Conventions -->
    <!-- <module name="AbbreviationAsWordInName"/> -->
    <module name="AbstractClassName"/>
    <module name="CatchParameterName"/>
    <module name="ClassTypeParameterName"/>
    <module name="ConstantName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="InterfaceTypeParameterName"/>
    <module name="LocalFinalVariableName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="LocalVariableName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MemberName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodTypeParameterName"/>
    <module name="PackageName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ParameterName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="StaticVariableName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="TypeName">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Regexp -->
    <!-- <module name="Regexp"/> -->
    <!-- <module name="RegexpSinglelineJava"/> -->

    <!-- Size Violations -->
    <module name="AnonInnerLength">
      <property name="max" value="100"/>
    </module>
    <!-- <module name="ExecutableStatementCount"/> -->
    <module name="LineLength">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="max" value="999"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodCount">
      <property name="maxTotal" value="110"/>
      <property name="maxPublic" value="110"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodLength">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="max" value="260"/>
    </module>
    <module name="OuterTypeNumber"/>
    <module name="ParameterNumber">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="max" value="9"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Whitespace  -->
    <module name="EmptyForInitializerPad"/>
    <module name="EmptyForIteratorPad">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyLineSeparator">
      <property name="allowMultipleEmptyLinesInsideClassMembers" value="false"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="IMPORT, CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, STATIC_INIT, INSTANCE_INIT, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="GenericWhitespace"/>
    <module name="MethodParamPad"/>
    <module name="NoLineWrap">
      <property name="tokens" value="IMPORT, PACKAGE_DEF"/> <!-- TODO , STATIC_IMPORT -->
    </module>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceAfter">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="ARRAY_INIT, INC, DEC, UNARY_MINUS, UNARY_PLUS, BNOT, LNOT, DOT, TYPECAST, ARRAY_DECLARATOR, INDEX_OP"/> <!-- TODO , AT, METHOD_REF -->
    </module>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="COMMA, SEMI, POST_INC, POST_DEC, DOT, GENERIC_START, GENERIC_END"/> <!-- TODO , ELLIPSIS, METHOD_REF -->
    </module>
    <module name="OperatorWrap">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="tokens" value=""/>
    </module>
    <module name="ParenPad">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="ANNOTATION, ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF, CTOR_CALL, CTOR_DEF, ENUM_CONSTANT_DEF, EXPR, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_NEW, LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED, LITERAL_WHILE, METHOD_CALL, METHOD_DEF, QUESTION, RESOURCE_SPECIFICATION, SUPER_CTOR_CALL"/> <!-- TODO , LAMBDA, DOT -->
    </module>
    <module name="SeparatorWrap">
      <property name="option" value="eol"/>
      <property name="tokens" value=""/>
    </module>
    <!-- TODO
    <module name="SingleSpaceSeparator"/>
    -->
    <module name="TypecastParenPad"/>
    <module name="WhitespaceAfter">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    </module>
    <module name="WhitespaceAround">
      <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="ASSIGN,BAND,BAND_ASSIGN,BOR,BOR_ASSIGN,BSR,BSR_ASSIGN,BXOR,BXOR_ASSIGN,COLON,DIV,DIV_ASSIGN,DO_WHILE,EQUAL,GE,GT,LAMBDA,LAND,LCURLY,LE,LITERAL_ASSERT,LITERAL_CATCH,LITERAL_DO,LITERAL_ELSE,LITERAL_FINALLY,LITERAL_FOR,LITERAL_IF,LITERAL_RETURN,LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED,LITERAL_TRY,LITERAL_WHILE,LOR,LT,MINUS,MINUS_ASSIGN,MOD,MOD_ASSIGN,NOT_EQUAL,PLUS,PLUS_ASSIGN,QUESTION,RCURLY,SL,SLIST,SL_ASSIGN,SR,SR_ASSIGN,STAR,STAR_ASSIGN,TYPE_EXTENSION_AND"/>
    </module>

  </module>

  <!-- Headers -->
  <!--
  <module name="Header">
    <property name="header" value=" * Copyright (C) 2018 Tec Media Services GmbH. All rights reserved!"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
  </module>
  -->

  <module name="RegexpHeader">
    <property name="header" value="^/\*\n \* Copyright \(C\) (\d\d\d\d)(-(\d\d\d\d))? Tec Media Services GmbH. All rights reserved!\n \*/$"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
  </module>

  <!-- Javadocs -->
  <!-- <module name="JavadocPackage"/> -->

  <!-- Misc -->
  <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile">
    <property name="lineSeparator" value="lf"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java,xml,dtd,properties,txt"/>
  </module>
  <module name="Translation"/>
  <module name="UniqueProperties"/>

  <!-- Regexp -->
  <!-- <module name="RegexpMultiline"/> -->
  <!-- <module name="RegexpOnFilename"/> -->
  <!-- <module name="RegexpSingleline"/> -->

  <!-- Size violations -->
  <module name="FileLength">
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    <property name="max" value="20000"/>
  </module>

  <!-- Whitespace -->
  <module name="FileTabCharacter">
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java,xml,dtd"/>
  </module>

</module>
```

Last but not least don't forget to also use your individual configuration within your IDE (like Eclipse) - so that you don't use the standard config with all the standard errors/warnings ;-)